# Using ClosedXML how to adjust row height to content?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I create cell with text. After that I set WrapText property and column width.

```
var cell = worksheet.Cell("A1");
cell.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
cell.SetValue("This is very long text");
worksheet.Column(1).Width = 10;
worksheet.Rows().AdjustToContents();
```

The text has been moved by words, but row height is not changed. How to adjust row height to cell content?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It works when you remove the `worksheet.Rows().AdjustToContents();`.

Autofitting sometimes needs more of a trial and error approach ...

Answer (score 18):

There are many ways to achieve this.

Don't use wrap or shrink properties on cell values rather include this line just before saving your excel

```
ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
```

Another way is to make use of Allignment property

```
 IXLRange titleRange = ws.Range("B2:AA2");
        titleRange.Cells().Style
            .Alignment.SetWrapText(true); // Its single statement
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bug of ClosedXML.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1243)

```
ws.Row(1).AdjustToContents();
ws.Row(1).ClearHeight();
```

In my case it works.
Version: 0.95.4

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
IXLRange contents = ws.Range("A1:A50");
contents.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also AdjustToContents on Specific range of cells.

```
worksheet.Columns(2, 20).AdjustToContents();
```

Comment: Question is about adjusting the height, not columns.

Comment: 7 Years later????? - I didn't remember the question :D

Comment: @SmitPatel In that case, it's best if you delete your answer, since it doesn't answer the question! It adds nothing new that the other (more upvoted) answers haven't already covered.

Comment: @Zimano - I've put it because of a Range can also be applied with AdjustToContents - Someone might have that question as well apart from what asked, As a developer we should think on wider level and don't need to stick to the exact question everytime.